# Need to fetch records from approval History which are assigned to Queue of which currently Loogged in User is part of

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

I have a requirement where i need to display Order records which are assigned to Queue of which Loged in User is part of.

Basically Need to fetch the Assignto Field from  Approval History and compare with Queue ID.

Please see the below Code that i am trying out:

```
 for(ProcessInstanceStep steps1 : [Select id,p.ActorId,p.processInstanceid,p.processInstance.id,p.processInstance.targetobject.id from 
                                                  ProcessInstanceStep  p where  p.OriginalActorId ='00Gi0000004qIOFEA2'  ]) {

                                TargetIDList.add(steps1.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId);    



                                system.debug('CheckRecords' + TargetIDList.size());
```

But unfortunatily its not returning any records..

Is i am using correct Field "OriginalActorId" of Steps in order to compare with Queue id here.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Id of the currently logged in user, take a look the static [UserInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) class, in particular the `getUserId()` method.

For context, `ActorId` pertains to the user who is *currently* assigned to the approval step, while `OriginalActorId` is the user who was *originally* assigned to the approval step when it was first created.